# Nextjs fetch cache max size problem, too much api calls

Tags: caching, next.js, fetch, size

With nextjs, the cache limit for a fetch is 2MB. However, some of my fetches are larger than 2 MB and the data is therefore not cached, which is very annoying because I make calls to my api again when I navigate to my component via Link (dynamique routes). The fetch is called as a preload, but the call to the api is also recalled a second time when the component is called, for all the routes concerned where I need to fetch this data. (so it makes 2 calls to my api instead of 0 for a every route)

So I have hundreds of calls to the api because of the cache limit... Do you have a solution to my problem? Maybe use something other fetching methods ?

thanks everyone

tried to reduce the size of my json fetched but its not a good solution in my case

Comment: This seems to be yet another hidden edge of Next.js.

Answer (score -2):

FIX

```
// Opt out of caching for an individual `fetch` request
fetch(`https://...`, { cache: 'no-store' })
```

***https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching***

```
// Opt out of caching for all data requests in the route segment
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```